# Add RTF/Rich Text Editor to CustomUserCreationForm/CustomUserEditForm

Tags: django, django-forms, rtf, wagtail

I try to extend my custom `User` model as described [here](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.2.2/advanced_topics/customisation/custom_user_models.html).
This works fine for the shown fields like `ModelChoiceField` and `CharField`.
My goal now is to add a `RTF` field (the control like the one shown in the `Page` model). I have looked through the source code of `wagtail` and found the method `get_rich_text_editor_widget` which is being used in conjunction with a `CharField`. Sadly I get a `JavaScript` error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'initEditor' of undefined

My guess now is that I somehow need to include or modify a hook for the widget. Or is it sufficient to override the `JavaScript` block in a template? It feels a bit hacky right now and I am stuck with including the required `JS`, that's why I am posting the question. Maybe I am missing something trivial.

```
# ...
from wagtail.admin.rich_text import get_rich_text_editor_widget

class CustomUserEditForm(UserEditForm):
    position = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Position.objects, required=True, label=_('Position'))
    # biography = forms.Textarea()
    biography = forms.CharField(widget=get_rich_text_editor_widget())
```

---

**Update:**
Updating my template (maybe not the right approach):

```
{% block js %}
{{ block.super }}

<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/wagtailadmin/js/draftail.js"></script>

{% endblock js %}
```

Results in:
[image]

Comment: You can also add `<link href="/static/wagtailadmin/css/panels/draftail.css" type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet">` to a `{% block extra_css %}`. What happens when you enter `window.draftail.initEditor` in your development console? You may compare your html to a regular page with a rich text editor and look for differences. What happens when you do `widget=get_rich_text_editor_widget(name='default', features=['h2'])`?

Comment: Adding your ``CSS`` styles the ``RTF`` field correctly. Basic functionality seems to work. Adding images/pages/documents lets the editor crash. Seems there is more related ``JS`` needed (e.g. ``TypeError: Cannot read property 'imageChooser' of undefined``) . Before adding the ``JS`` ``window.draftail`` was undefined. Now it returns the function. Passing the ``args`` works as expected. Adding the functionality through the template may be a solution but I couldn't find all the references needed and hope for a more declarative way to import them.

Comment: I think the page templates _do_ have all the context richtext (Draftail) needs. I can imagine the use of Draftail in other contexts (like the User model view) isn't even considered by the original author(s). It might be a nice to have feature for Wagtail. But that doesn't help you in the short term. I think deduction is quickest. Load _all_ js from a regular page and remove scripts one by one until you have the minimal set required. Dirty, but should work TM.

Answer (score 1):

I've written my solution up as an issue for draftail

https://github.com/springload/draftail/issues/450

I've got a wagtail site with this awesome RichText Editor (called Draftail) but trying to use it on a non Wagtail Admin page makes me feel dirty.  I wanted a biography field that people could write about themselves and I wanted the blog authors to be able to use it as well.  BUT to do that I've had to do some things that make me cringe.

Not bad:

```
{% block extra_css %}
  <link href="{% static 'wagtailadmin/css/panels/draftail.css' %}" type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet">
{% endblock extra_css %}
```

WTF???? why aren't we just using Favicons for things like Bold

```
    <div data-sprite></div>
    <script>
        function loadIconSprite() {
            var spriteURL = '{% url "wagtailadmin_sprite" %}';
            var revisionKey = 'wagtail:spriteRevision';
            var dataKey = 'wagtail:spriteData';
            var isLocalStorage = 'localStorage' in window && typeof window.localStorage !== 'undefined';

            var insertIt = function (data) {
                var spriteContainer = document.body.querySelector('[data-sprite]');
                spriteContainer.innerHTML = data;
            }

            var insert = function (data) {
                if (document.body) {
                    insertIt(data)
                } else {
                    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', insertIt.bind(null, data));
                }
            }

            if (isLocalStorage && localStorage.getItem(revisionKey) === spriteURL) {
                var data = localStorage.getItem(dataKey);
                if (data) {
                    insert(data);
                    return true;
                }
            }

            try {
                var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                request.open('GET', spriteURL, true);
                request.onload = function () {
                    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
                        data = request.responseText;
                        insert(data);
                        if (isLocalStorage) {
                            localStorage.setItem(dataKey, data);
                            localStorage.setItem(revisionKey, spriteURL);
                        }
                    }
                }
                request.send();
            } catch (e) {
                console.error(e);
            }
        }
        loadIconSprite();
    </script>
```

Because wagtail comments.js somehow needs wagtailConfig.ADMIN_API and draftail won't initialize without comments.js

```
      <script>
        (function(document, window) {
            window.wagtailConfig = window.wagtailConfig || {};
            wagtailConfig.ADMIN_API = {
                PAGES: '',
                DOCUMENTS: '',
                IMAGES: '',
                {# // Use this to add an extra query string on all API requests. #}
                {# // Example value: '&order=-id' #}
                EXTRA_CHILDREN_PARAMETERS: '',
            };

            {% i18n_enabled as i18n_enabled %}
            {% locales as locales %}
            wagtailConfig.I18N_ENABLED = {% if i18n_enabled %}true{% else %}false{% endif %};
            wagtailConfig.LOCALES = {{ locales|safe }};

            wagtailConfig.STRINGS = {% js_translation_strings %};

            wagtailConfig.ADMIN_URLS = {
                PAGES: ''
            };
        })(document, window);
    </script>
    <script src="{% static 'wagtailadmin/js/vendor/jquery-3.5.1.min.js' %}"></script>
    <!-- <script src="{% static 'wagtailadmin/js/core.js' %}"></script> strangely not needed -->
    <script src="{% static 'wagtailadmin/js/vendor.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'wagtailadmin/js/comments.js' %}"></script>
    {{ form.media.js }}
```

All of this just to get the draftail editor on a non wagtail admin page!

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. My problem with such an approach is that it feels way too hacky to actually use this for production. Thanks for issuing this as a feature request to improve wagtail. Let's see what gasman has to say to it.